# How to add resources to the classpath of Maven plugins?

Tags: maven

I've got a Maven plugin that depends on slf4j for logging. The default behavior is too chatty for my liking but I can't figure out how to add my `logback.xml` to the plugin's classpath.

```
<plugin>
  <dependencies>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

allows you to add dependencies to the plugin's classpath, but how do you add local (resource) directories?

Comment: Can you tell us which plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise: It shouldn't matter, but in my case it's http://www.jooq.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your logback.xml into a proper Maven artifact (i.e. a jar) and install it to local repository or deploy to your shared repository, or use systemPath in your dependency declaration to point to a jar placed somewhere inside of your project, which is highly not recommended.

The reason for this is reusability of your build. Think how others would be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Are you honesty telling me that I need to create an entire artifact to contain logback.xml? There would be not reusability problem if I was allowed to add the project's resources directory to the plugin's classpath.

Comment: It will take you less then a minute to create a jar with your logback.xml in it. There are a lot of happening in Maven under the hood, so adding project folders to plugin classpath is not exactly fit into the Maven plugin model. Unlike a folder, an artifact is a versioned entity, maybe it is unimportant in your case, but it is critical for an overall Maven's plugin classpath resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You must package them up as an artifact and add it as a dependency.